# Find out whether a whole folder structure exists (CMD Batch)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, directory, cmd

I feel like this should be easy to do, but can't quite figure it out on my own. 
Perhaps someone is able to help.

I have this tiny batch script that basically checks whether a folder `Folder1` already exists or not. If it doesn't, it will create `Folder1` to `Folder6`. If it does, it will simply echo this fact.

```
@ECHO OFF
If not exist Folder1 (for /L %%a in (1,1,6) do md Folder%%a) else (ECHO Folder structure already exists)
```

What I want to do now is replace the `If not exist Folder1` with something that makes a tad more sense. I. e. `If not exist folder with any string greater or equal to 'Folder'`

Any way I would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,6) do md Folder%%a
```

be easier, and create the directories whether or not they already exist?

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,6) do md Folder%%a 2>nul
```

should suppress messages for already-existing directories.

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

```
rem if not exist folder
if not exist "folder1" (
    rem with any string greater or equal to 'Folder'
    if "folder1" geq "Folder" (
        rem do sth.
        rem do sth. more
    )
)
```

Comment: Ooh OMG! ... I only write down, what the OP needs, obviously I'm a writer, not a thinker `:-)`

Comment: Oh. So greater or equal is always true, no matter what? Darn. Then this isn't gonna cut it. PS: the task at hand is actually something I might need to do on evaluation day (next Monday), which is why I'm specifically looking for the "correct" way. Otherwise, I'd probably just surpress the messages and be done with it.

Comment: @user2534826 for better answers please try to ask more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. What I, essentially, want to do is check whether folders 1-6 (Folder1, Folder2, Folder3, etc.) already exist. And if they don't, I want the script to create them. My current script only checks whether Folder1 exists or not, which isn't quite practical.

Comment: You can take Peter's answer, it will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "flag="
for /L %%a in (1,1,6) do if not exist "Folder%%a\" set flag=1
if defined flag (
echo at least one of your folders is missing captain.
for /L %%a in (1,1,6) do md Folder%%a 2>nul
) else (
echo Warp speed, no folders to create
)
```